# Clustering a Scheduled job with JBoss 6

Tags: jboss, scheduled-tasks, jboss6.x, cluster-computing

I have a regular task that has to be executed once per day (but only once). Currently this is done with a @Schedule annotation.

next i want to cluster my application. is there anything i have to do so my scheduled task is properly executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds promising:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HASingletonDeployer